# Select-style dropdown in Angularjs disappears after selection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am attempting to create a select-style dropdown list with angular js. My immediate problem is that once the user makes a "selection", the list goes completely blank.

When I run the following in jsfiddle, the dropdown menu works as expected and the {{languageList.label}} populates the selected label from the list. (I see this is an older version of angularjs...)

http://jsfiddle.net/8wcrkf5z/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="LanguageController">     
    {{message}}
    <select ng-model="languageList" ng-options="language as language.label for language in languages">           
    </select>
    <p>Selected: {{languageList.label}}</p>
<div>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function LanguageController($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Select language: "
    // language options
    $scope.languages = [{
      value: 'eng',
      label: 'English'
    }, {
      value: 'ger',
      label: 'German'
    }, {
      value: 'frc',
      label: 'French (Canada)'
    }, {
      value: 'frf',
      label: 'French (France)'
    }, {
      value: 'ara',
      label: 'Arabic'
    }];    
}
```

I have had some difficulty porting this over to the current version of Angular js, but I have cobbled together the following on Plunker, although the dropdown menu populates correctly, once you make a selection, it goes completely blank, and the {{language.label}} does not update with the selection.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8v4qin

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="LanguageController">
    <!--<h1>{{ message }}</h1>-->
    <select name="languageList" ng-model="languages" ng-options="language as language.label for language in languages"></select>
    <h2>Selected Language: {{languageList.label}}</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('LanguageController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    //$scope.message = "Please choose a language"
    // language options
    $scope.languages = [{
      value: 'eng',
      label: 'English'
    }, {
      value: 'ger',
      label: 'German'
    }, {
      value: 'frc',
      label: 'French (Canada)'
    }, {
      value: 'frf',
      label: 'French (France)'
    }, {
      value: 'ara',
      label: 'Arabic'
    }];
}]);
```

Here is the *before* from Plunker preview:

[image]

And here is after the user makes selection:

[image]

Comment: You have `ng-model="languages"` in the `<select>` so once you make a selection, it overrides the `languages` array. Your earlier (jsFiddle) version has `ng-model="languageList"`. Fixed here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/yTHOX3TcgYpl3BqQsDgV?p=preview

Comment: OK thanks @Phil so that appears to be an obvious dummy move (typo) on my end... Short of double- and triple-checking, is there any way to detect this sort of blunder? Dev tools doesn't raise any errors on the preview in Plunker.

Comment: That's because there was no error. Typically, one would use unit tests to discover bugs like this.

Comment: Ok I'm about 6 hours into angular and this is essentially the first thing I've really tried to do,  so I'll have to brush up on that as a debugging technique. Thanks again @Phil

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult. Check out the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project for examples